# Kong Admin api authentication

Tags: rest, routes, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I am running kong in kubernetes cluster, kong-admin-api has no authentication, anyone with the nodePort can CRUD service or routes.
Is there any way we can have some authentication.
I don't want to run kong as a localhost. It will be running as 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There is whole documentation is available on securing the kong admin api.

https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/1.0.x/secure-admin-api/

you can use the network restrict policy or enable the basic authentication policy on admin API if possible you can also **IP restrict**.

you also try another approach to change the service type to **ClusterIP** and call the admin API internally only if want to use GUI **Konga** is there with user management.